# How to map Caps Lock as a second Control Key on a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000?

Tags: macos, keyboard, microsoft

I've got a **Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000**, with the latest IntelliType drivers installed. There is an option to swap a **Caps Lock** and a **Control key** in the **Microsoft Keyboard** preferences pane, but no way to use **Caps Lock** as a second **Control key**.

Changing the Modifier Keys in **System Preferences > Keyboard** helps, but resets after the restart. Reset happens only when **Microsoft Keyboard Helper** is launched. These settings were always saved after the restart with another third-party keyboard I've been using before.

Using **ControllerMate** helps, but it's slow, buggy and, obviously, a huge overkill for my needs.

**KeyRemap4MacBook** and **PCKeyboardHack** are not working. I guess Microsoft Keyboard driver overrules them.

Repairing permissions does not help either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two months went past, and a "legitimate" solution is nowhere to be seen. Fortunately, there is a simpler and a more radical way to solve this, and all related issues — getting rid of the crappy Microsoft drivers completely. <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, and other modifier key mappings, are easily changed in the "Keyboard" preferences. <kbd>Play/Pause</kbd>, <kbd>Volume</kbd> and <kbd>Mute</kbd> keys are working perfectly.
All of the other media keys, and the "Zoom" slider are predictably dead, but I've never used them anyway. The "Application" or "Menu key" is mapped to <kbd>⌘</kbd> with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/).

Comment: YAY!

Finding this answer meant that I could finally get my keyboard to work again (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/363319 ).

The only thing I'd add is that the way to uninstall the Microsoft drivers is through the programs "Intellitype Uninstaller" and "Intellipoint Uninstaller" found in Applications/Utilities.